# Google Chart with Category Picker and SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, bar-chart

I want to draw a google chart with data comes from a stored procedure in MS SQL and also use a category picker.
So far my code only show a blank page and i don't know where is the mistake.

The stored procedure return a table which looks like this

Time | Room1 | Room2 | Room3 | Room4

9:00 | 0     |   10  |   0   |  5

10:00| 15    |   2   |  20   |  0

11:00|  5    |   4   |   15  |   6

My code for the aspx.cs is:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    string ChartData = GetChartData();
    chart.Text=@"<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls','corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    function drawVisualization() {
        // Prepare the data
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Time');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Room');
        data.addRows(["+ChartData+@" ]);

        var options = { 
                    'title': 'Chart',            
                    'seriesType': 'bars',                               
        }; 

        var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
            containerId: 'control2',
            options: {
                filterColumnLabel: 'Room',
                ui: {
                    labelStacking: 'vertical',
                    allowTyping: false,
                    allowMultiple: false,
                    height: 100
                }
            },
            state: {
                selectedValues: ['Room1']
            }
        });

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker, 'statechange');

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
        dashboard.bind(categoryPicker);
        chart.draw(data, options);  
    }   
    </script>";
}  

protected string GetChartData()  
{  

    string ChartData = string.Empty;    
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("xxxx");
        string Cmdstring = "Select * from table";
        SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand(Cmdstring,sqlCon);
        sqlCon.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read()){
        ChartData += "['" +reader["Time"].ToString()+"',"+reader["Room1"].ToString()+"',"+reader["Room2"].ToString()+"',"+reader["Room3"].ToString()+"',"+reader["Room4"].ToString()+ "],";
    }
    if(ChartData.Length >0){
        ChartData = ChartData.Substring(0, ChartData.Length -1);
    }
    return ChartData;  
}
```

and My aspx is

```
<head runat="server">  
<title>Charts Example</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>  
</head>  
<body>  

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="control2"></div> 
<div id="dashboard"></div> 
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 660px; height: 400px;"></div>  
 <asp:Literal ID="chart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>  

</form>

</body>
```

Could you help me to find the mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a couple of things:

- You need to also load the corechart library in order to get ComboChart.

  ```
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls','corechart']});
  ```
- The code for the dashboard is missing a few things. Make sure you have a div with an ID of Dashboard in your html (it is missing), and then use

  ```
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));
  dashboard.bind(categoryPicker);
  ```
- Your column setup doesn't match your data. You need to have as many columns as you have in your data, and they need to be in number format.

Here's how I imagine the page should look like when all is set up:

http://jsfiddle.net/0h62ugd4/

Comment: thanks, i edit my question with the changes you said, but i still got a blank page.

Comment: I added more suggestions and a jsfiddle.

Comment: thanks I change the number of colum i find some mistake using the F12 like you say, now i can see the graph but like in your jsfiddle my category picker doesn't show and i got "undefined does not fit either the Control or Visualization specification.×" what is the meaning of it? expect this i don't get any other errors

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but see the updated fiddle above.

Comment: thanks, works well. to finish i would like to select by room and not by time. I understand it follow the filterColumnIndex so far but is it possible to put something else to get the room? this way the category picket will show 'room1, room2, room3, room4'

Comment: Your data is in the wrong format, you need to have columns as your times, and rooms for the rows. You'll have to change your sql to pivot the data this way so that your data comes out like this: http://jsfiddle.net/astafo1L/.